# Trigger just one of multiple UpdateProgress in an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a page content area with an asp:UpdatePanel, and inside that is a gridview. Inside that gridview each row has a button and an UpdateProgress that is linked to the UpdatePanel for the page content area.

It works as expected, where if you click any of the buttons all of the UpdateProgress will trigger because they are all linked to the same UpdatePanel, however I would like only the one next to the button to trigger.

Example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlContent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Then every gridview row has a:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="uprogrow" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="unplContent" 
     DisplayAfter="0">
```

Comment: What does your code behind look like? Do you use an event in code behind? Even if they all are wired to the same event you can cast the sender to get the right control and update that one.

Comment: Updated my post to show the code.